# How can I pass on parameters 4..99 to another function

Tags: bash, scripting, function, parameter

I'm calling a function and I want to pass up to 100 paramters onto another function.  I do not want to pass on the first 3 params, I start with param4 being the first param for the other program.

I am currently allowing for passing on up to 19 additional with

```
$function_under_test "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7" "$8" "$9" "${10}" "${11}" "${12}" 
  "${13}" "${14}" "${15}" "${16}" "${17}" "${18}" "${19}"
```

but this is not very substanable for larger sets of params.

I tried

```
  declare -a pass_on_params
  for ((a=2; a<$#; a++)); do
    pass_on_params+=(${@[a]})  # line 8
  done
  echo "->" $pass_on_params
```

but I get

```
do_test.sh: line 8: ${@[a]}: bad substitution
```

Full code is:

```
do_test () {
  function_under_test=$1
  line_number=$2
  expected="$3"
  param1="$4"
  declare -a pass_on_params
  for ((a=2; a<$#; a++)); do
    pass_on_params+=(${@[a]})
  done
  echo "ppppppppp" $pass_on_params
  $function_under_test "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7" "$8" "$9" "${10}" "${11}" "${12}" "${13}" "${14}" "${15}" "${16}" "${17}" "${18}" "${19}"
  if [ $result -eq $expected ]; then
    printf '.'
  else
    printf 'F'
    error_messages=$error_messages"Call to '$function_under_test $param1' failed: $result was not equal to $expected at line $line_number\n"
  fi
}
```

Shell is bash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"${@:4}"` works for me in bash. You can also assign to another array and do indexing on it:

```
foo=("$@")
second_function "${foo[@]:4}"
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use another function:

```
fn(){
    pass(){
        shift "$shift"
        "$other" "$@"
    }
    other=fn2 shift=3 pass "$@"
    unset -f pass
}
```

It would be better, though, to iterate over the args in an organized way. Like...

```
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]
do    : something with "$1"
shift;done
```

..or..

```
for arg do : something with "$arg"; done
```

...but it's hard to tell what you're doing.

You can safely `eval`uate math expressions into positional parameters if you handle the quoting right:

```
eval "fn2 $(i=3
    until [ "$#" -le 3 ]
    do    printf '"${%d}" ' "$((i+=1))"
    shift;done
)"
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to shift three times and pass $@

Full code is:

```
do_test () {
  function_under_test=$1;shift
  line_number=$1;shift
  expected="$1";shift
  echo "ppppppppp" $@
  $function_under_test "$@"
  if [ $result -eq $expected ]; then
    printf '.'
  else
    printf 'F'
    error_messages=$error_messages"Call to '$function_under_test $param1' failed: $result was not equal to $expected at line $line_number\n"
  fi
}
```